# Linux time command with high precision

Tags: linux, gcc, time, compilation

I was wondering if there is any linux command (like time or /usr/bin/time) that provides the execution time of one command with high precision in nanoseconds

Answer (score 4):

`strace -c` will count system time in microseconds

`strace -ttt` will show time of day (with microseconds) for each line of output.

Getting a total time in nanoseconds is probably not useful, because the jitter due to forking and process startup will be orders of magnitude larger than a nanosecond anyway.

Comment: is it possible to get a formatted output from strace -c CMD? I want just the time value

Comment: So use `tail` and/or `awk`

Comment: However strace -c provide system time, I need to get the clock (user) time.

Comment: `strace -ttt` is the time of day, that should be wall time. Or write your own version of `time` that uses `clock_gettime`. There is no existing utility that prints nanoseconds, because as I said it's not very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to find any ready-to-use tool, and wrote myself:

```
$ cat precision-time
#!/bin/bash
start="$(date +'%s.%N')"
$@
echo "$(date +"%s.%N - ${start}" | bc)" >&2
```

Usage:

```
$ ./precision-time sleep 1
1.002805151
```